# How to echo to a file in perl instead of bash

Tags: perl

In bash, I'm use to echoing something to a file like this:

```
echo "$contents" >file.txt
```

In perl, I have the say command doing this:

```
say for $jsondata->{"Name"};
```

I want to save that output to a file.
I tried

```
say for $jsondata->{"Name"} >tempfile;
```

but its not working.

Comment: You can open a file and `print` (or `say`) to the file.  Or you can use `system` (but that is ugly and non-Perlish).  Or, at a pinch, you can use `qx//` or the back-ticks, also ugly and not very Perlish.  But it is Perl: TMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open a filehandle:

```
open my $fh, '>', '/path/to/file' or die "Unable to open file: $!";
```

and then write to it:

```
say $fh $_ for $jsondata->{"Name"};
```

or (see Borodin's comment to this answer):

```
say $fh $jsondata->{Name};
```

Comment: `$jsondata->{"Name"}` cannot be anything other than a scalar value, so `for` is superfluous. It is also usually neater to omit the quotes around a literal hash key when that key contains only *word* characters (alphanumeric or underscore). So I would prefer `say $fh $jsondata->{Name}`